# Why am I getting TypeError on code that worked previously?

Tags: python, json, typeerror, file-conversion

I have this code to iterate through a json file. The user specifies tiers to be extracted, the names of which are then saved in inputLabels, and this for loop extracts the data from those tiers:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='\r\n') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for line in data:
            if line['label'] in inputLabels:
                elements = [(e['body']['value']).replace(" ", "_") + "\t" for e in line['first']['items']]
                outputData.append(elements)
```

I wrote this code a year ago and have run it multiple times since then with no issues, but running it today I received a TypeError.

```
    if line['label'] in inputLabels:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't understand why my code was able to work before if this is a true TypeError. Why is this only a problem in the code now, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Pasted part of the json:

```
{
  "contains": [
    {
      "total": 118,
      "generated": "ELAN Multimedia Annotator 6.2",
      "id": "xxx",
      "label": "BAR001_TEXT",
      "type": "AnnotationCollection",
      "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp.jsonld",
      "first": {
        "startIndex": "0",
        "id": "xxx",
        "type": "AnnotationPage",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "xxx",
            "type": "Annotation",
            "body": {
              "purpose": "transcribing",
              "format": "text/plain",
              "language": "",
              "type": "TextualBody",
              "value": ""
            },
        "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld",
        "target": {
          "format": "audio/x-wav",
          "id": "xxx",
          "type": "Audio"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "xxx",
        "type": "Annotation",
        "body": {
          "purpose": "transcribing",
          "format": "text/plain",
          "language": "",
          "type": "TextualBody",
          "value": "Dobar vam"
        },
        "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld",
        "target": {
          "format": "audio/x-wav",
          "id": "xxx",
          "type": "Audio"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "xxx",
        "type": "Annotation",
        "body": {
          "purpose": "transcribing",
          "format": "text/plain",
          "language": "",
          "type": "TextualBody",
          "value": "Je"
        },
        "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld",
        "target": {
          "format": "audio/x-wav",
          "id": "xxx",
          "type": "Audio"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Could you post what the JSON file looks like?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the JSON file. Can you share the JSON you are facing the issue with?

Comment: I think there is an entry in the JSON without a key perhaps, so `line` is a string and not a dictionary.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj you're right, I just ran the code on a previous JSON file and the code worked, so there is some sort of problem in the current JSON file. I'm not very familiar with JSON so not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would probably work if you replaced `for line in data:` with `for line in data['contains']`

Maybe the JSON schema didn't have the `"contains"` level previously.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty pythonic approach would be using exceptions:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='\r\n') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for line in data:
            try:
                if line['label'] in inputLabels:
                    elements = [(e['body']['value']).replace(" ", "_") + "\t" for e in line['first']['items']]
                    outputData.append(elements)
            except Exception as e:
                print( f"{type(e)} : {e} when trying to use {line}")
```

Your code will run through and give you a hint about what failed

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a pretty simple fix. All of the JSON file was in a container (look at the portion I posted in the question, it's the second line, "contains":). I was able to just remove that container and its open/closing brackets and the code ran successfully after that. Thanks all for your help.